# Random "virtualPath" error - Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net, internationalization

The full error is - "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: virtualPath". This is occurring in our QA and Training environments (Win 2003 Server & IIS6) but of course defies recreation in a debugger. To make matters worse, despite a reasonable global error handler, no stack trace accompanies the error and nothing is written to the event log. The app is a large fully globalized Asp.Net (VB) web application running under the 2.0 Framework. It uses the usual "App_LocalResources" structure for resx files and to date has performed quite well. There are several places in the app where code like this is used:

```
Dim x As New Compilation.ExpressionBuilderContext(Control.TemplateControl)  
Dim path As String = x.VirtualPath  
Dim res As String = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(path, resourceKey).ToString
```

However the Try/Catch block around this code works properly when I force the "path" variable to be nothing. We also use this syntax everywhere for data grid column headers:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="<%$ Resources:resHeader %>" >
```

We also use a considerable amount of Ajax and dynamically load ascx controls into placeholders constantly. If anyone has any insight into this I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks, Larry

Answer (score 1):

Follow up - make sure your servers are up to the proper patch level.
The root cause of this turned out to be 3 QA VMs that did not have
2.0 .Net Framework SP1 installed.

Answer (score 0):

this might sound silly, but heck i have had this happen to me before.

if you copy and pasted your error, i notice it says "virtualPath" (lower case v); whil in your sample code, the property you use has VirtualPath (upper case V).

Also, what is the actual exception you are getting? a NullReferenceException?